# What does Error code ‎8007203c mean? In Windows Active directory?

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

When I try to change Group attributes using C++ Native code, I get this error:  ‎8007203c. What does this error code refer to? I can't find details regarding this in documents.

Answer (score 3):

The error code is defined as ERROR_DS_ENCODING_ERROR in `winerror.h`:

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_DS_ENCODING_ERROR
//
// MessageText:
//
// An encoding error has occurred.
//
#define ERROR_DS_ENCODING_ERROR          8252L
```

An easier way to lookup error code is to search in The Magic Number Database: https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=8007203c

So this is probably an encoding (ansi vs unicode) issue or maybe using special characters that should be escaped. From Active Directory: [Characters to Escape](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx): [image]

Answer (score 1):

As for my knowledge, this error occurs if there is an invalid code page, invalid characters or an encoding error (can't find the reference/documentation about it yet).

Maybe there are special characters in your group names which cause this behavior.